# How to build/install caffe2 in windows?

Tags: python, cmake, caffe2

I have tried setting up caffe2 in windows 10 by cloning the pytorch repo and trying to build from source since binaries are not available for windows platform.

But whenever I run the `build_windows.bat` file in `pytorch/scripts`, I end up getting the error

```
CMake Error at cmake/Codegen.cmake:163 (message):
  Failed to get generated_cpp list
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    caffe2/CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Python - 2.7.13

CMake - 3.13.4

CUDA - 10.0

I was following the instructions [here](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=windows&configuration=compile). But the build fails after couple of minutes after starting when `BUILD_PYTHON` is set to `ON`.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, then I realized it was caused by cmake configuration. Maybe it points to a wrong python interpreter.

You could try to open the build_windows.bat, edit the '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE' (should in line 85) to the absolute directory of your python.exe (It will look like '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="E:\python\python.exe"' after edition) and run it again. Hope this help!

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks!
I'm planning to setup Detectron along with this. Any tips that might help?

Comment: I do not use that, so am afraid could not help on this :(

Comment: Ah no worries. Do you know how to build it with gpu support? Mine says it will run only in cpu mode.

Comment: Hi @RakihthaRR, where you able to install detectron? I am also planning to and have hit the exact same error with Caffe2

Comment: @El_1988 I did, but unfortunately, there were a lot of issues. So I switched to Linux.